# HIPAA Compliance: Disconnected RDP Sessions

Tags: security, windows-server-2012-r2, rdp

A simple question that I can't seem to find an answer to.  As you know, Windows Server allows you to set an auto-logout for RDP sessions.  Is disabling this entirely (allowing RDP sessions to exist in perpetuity), in a virtual environment with ePHI, a security risk / HIPAA violation?

The VMs in question sit behind a fully configured Juniper firewall with IP restrictions on RDP access.

Comment: Well disconnected RDP sessions are still protected as if the user is logged on. Most places have a HIPPA security/compliance officer that knows the regulations better.

Answer (score 0):

We are not able to answer about your environment. You need a compliance person to review your system as a whole.

Note that automatic logoff is mentioned explicitly in regulation:

> [AUTOMATIC LOGOFF - § 164.312(a)(2)(iii)](https://www.hhs.gov/sites/default/files/ocr/privacy/hipaa/administrative/securityrule/techsafeguards.pdf)
>
> Where this implementation
> specification is a reasonable and appropriate safeguard for a covered
> entity, the covered entity must:
>
> “Implement electronic procedures that
> terminate an electronic session after a predetermined time of
> inactivity.”

And think about it for a minute: this will let users show sensitive information on the screen indefinitely. Consider your own medical history. If that is undesirable, how are you going to address it?

More importantly, the HIPPA security series of papers describes a comprehensive strategy. Administrative processes, physical security, technical safeguards, documentation, and risk management. Network security does not do you any good if, say, staff shout information to the waiting room, and there is no technical solution to that.

Comment: Thanks.  Obviously, I wasn't looking for a professional opinion. It was simply an interesting question I was thinking of.  Although the statement above is true about letting "users show sensitive information on the screen indefinitely.", this is a virtual environment, and we're talking about RDP sessions into a VM that has no physical monitor.  Even if you were to console to the VM via vmWare, you'd be looking at the logon screen, since it would be a remote session.

Comment: Don't forget users on their end devices not logging off. That the application with PHI is deployed via remote VM does not change the requirement to consider shut down the session after inactivity.  The application might do so, but if not some other means could be used.  Which is why I said the answer depends on your environment.